# How i can send email using node.js without using third party

Tags: node.js

I will send emails using node.js but without using the third party. In node, I send emails using node-mailer or send an email, etc. But I send emails without using the third party.

Comment: Node does not support SMTP natively afaik, so without using a library like node-mailer etc. you cannot.

Comment: Well you actually can execute linux commands. So you can try to use `child_process.exec`. And from there run mail command `exec('sendmail user@example.com  < /tmp/email.txt')`. But i would not say that this is ideal approach.

Comment: NodeMailer , but the recommended way is to use a service. mailtrap also free to use for testing .